# extract data from http response in jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

This is the json data im getting after running a http request in jmeter.

```js
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            },
            "resource": {
                "meta": {
                    "lastUpdated": "2018-10-29T08:37:53.351+00:00",
                    "versionId": "aa1e1cc3-8018-408e-a70a-4885004720fa",
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "http:\/\/hl7.org\/fhir\/v3\/ObservationValue",
                            "code": "SUBSETTED"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": [
                    {
                        "given": [
                            "Aaron697"
                        ],
                        "use": "official",
                        "prefix": [
                            "Mr."
                        ],
                        "family": "Abernathy524"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "176b8fef-5a62-48da-b82e-4722843d9f2d",
                "resourceType": "Patient"
            },
            "fullUrl": "http:\/\/localhost:4080\/Patient\/176b8fef-5a62-48da-b82e-4722843d9f2d"
        },
        {
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            },
            "resource": {
                "meta": {
                    "lastUpdated": "2018-10-29T08:09:33.67+00:00",
                    "versionId": "c852310e-8894-45dd-a87c-9e449950caf4",
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "http:\/\/hl7.org\/fhir\/v3\/ObservationValue",
                            "code": "SUBSETTED"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": [
                    {
                        "given": [
                            "Aaron697"
                        ],
                        "use": "official",
                        "prefix": [
                            "Mr."
                        ],
                        "family": "Abernathy524"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "8bbb3bb7-4e5b-48bd-82af-8463c4060de3",
                "resourceType": "Patient"
            },
            "fullUrl": "http:\/\/localhost:4080\/Patient\/8bbb3bb7-4e5b-48bd-82af-8463c4060de3"
        }
  ]
}
```

Now i have to extract all the id's and name.use, name.given, name.family, name.prefix into corresponding csv files.
eg: id into id.csv file; name.given into name_given.csv file etc...
the http request can contain n number of id's and names. How to do that?
i have tried and failed using json extract and regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into Script area:

   ```
   import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

   def idCSV = new File('id.csv')
   def nameGiven = new File('name_given.csv')
   def nameFamily = new File('name_family.csv')
   def namePrefix = new File('name_prefix.csv')
   def newLine = System.getProperty('line.separator')

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

   def ids = JsonPath.read(response, '$..id')

   ids.each { id ->
       idCSV << id << newLine
   }

   def names = JsonPath.read(response, '$..name')
   names.each { name ->
       name.each { subName ->
           subName.get('given').each { givenName ->
               nameGiven << givenName << newLine
           }
           subName.get('prefix').each { prefix ->
               namePrefix << prefix << newLine
           }

           nameFamily << subName.get('family') << newLine
       }

   }
   ```
3. That's it, the code will extract the required data from the response and store it into the following files

   - id.csv
   - name_given.csv
   - name_family.csv
   - name_prefix.csv

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you sir this solution is working awesome, and thank you for sharing the references.

Comment: sir how to access ids with index. i.e how to get value of ids[0], ids[1] like this, without using each loop